# Ono-to-one-function vs zero-determinant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $G : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{T}$ be a continuous, differentiable and bijective function from a manifolds $\mathcal{S}$ to a manifolds $\mathcal{T}$. Let $J(G(x))$ be the Jacobian of $G$ at a point $x \in \mathcal{S}$ and $| J(G(x)) |$ the corresponding matrix determinant.

My conjecture is that $| J(G(x)) | \neq 0$ in all $x \in \mathcal{S}/\mathcal{R}$, where $\mathcal{R}$ is a measure zero set. In other words, can I claim that it does not exist an interval $[a,b] \in \mathcal{S}$, where $a < b$, such that $| J(G(x)) | = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$? This fact seems to be reasonable and intuitive in one-dimansional spaces as the bijectivity of a continous and differentiable function entails that the function cannot have the same value in an interval (otherwise it would not be bijective), so that its derivative cannot be zero in an interval.

Example.

Let $G(x) = x^3$ and  $| J(G(x)) | = 3x^2$. You can see that $| J(G(x)) | = 0$ in a set of measure zero (only when $x=0$). Could this fact be generalized to higher dimensional spaces?

Comment: If $S$ is $2$ or more dimensional, then intervals have measure $0$.  So, I'm not exactly sure what your conjecture is...  I guess you're also assuming $S$ and $T$ have the same dimension, otherwise the Jacobian doesn't have a determinant at all.